# Writing a value defined with EQU to the console using Linux system calls

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, system-calls

to write to console text pointed by some label I am using below code:

```
section .data                           ;Data segment
   userMsg db 'Please enter a number: ' ;Ask the user to enter a number
   lenUserMsg equ $-userMsg             ;The length of the message             


section .text          ;Code Segment
   global _start

_start:                
   ;User prompt
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, userMsg
   mov edx, lenUserMsg
   int 80h

   ; Exit code
   mov eax, 1
   mov ebx, 0
   int 80h
```

but what if I want to write to console value stored under lenUserMsg value ?

I have tried below:

```
   ...
   ;User prompt
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, lenUserMsg
   mov edx, 1
   int 80h
   ...
```

it compile and run without crash but write nothing to console.

Comment: That's because `lenUserMsg` is not the address of a message. It's the length of the message at address `userMsg`.

Comment: passing a bad address to `write(2)` doesn't make your program crash.  It makes the kernel return `-EFAULT`.  You have to pass `write(2)` an address, not a value.  Run your program under `strace` to see what system calls it makes, and what the return values are.  (much easier than writing code to check args / return values yourself for experiments / toy programs, and also easier than single-stepping in a debugger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lenUserMsg` is not stored. The `EQU` directive causes it to be just a macro which value (a string!) is calculated at assemble time and which replaces any occurence of its "name". There is no chance to get its value at runtime. If you want a value that is stored in the `.data` section you can define it like any other value - with brackets. I guess you want to see the decimal representation of `lenUserMsg` since `Int 80h/EAX=4` only prints strings, so I added a conversion routine the following example:

```
section .data                            ;Data segment
    userMsg db 'Please enter a number: ' ;Ask the user to enter a number
    lenUserMsg dd $-userMsg              ;The length of the message

section .bss
    buf resb 16

section .text          ;Code Segment
global _start

_start:
    ;User prompt
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, userMsg
    mov edx, [lenUserMsg]
    int 80h

    mov eax, [lenUserMsg]
    mov edi, buf
    call EAX_to_DEC

    mov edx, eax
    mov ecx, buf
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h

    ; Exit code
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

EAX_to_DEC:                     ; ARG: EDI pointer to string buffer
    mov ebx, 10                 ; Divisor = 10
    xor ecx, ecx                ; ECX=0 (digit counter)
    .L1:                        ; First Loop: store the remainders
    xor edx, edx                ; Don't forget it!
    div ebx                     ; EDX:EAX / EBX = EAX remainder EDX
    push dx                     ; Push the digit in DL (LIFO)
    add cl, 1                   ; = inc cl (digit counter)
    or eax, eax                 ; AX == 0?
    jnz .L1                     ; No: once more (jump to the first @@ above)
    mov ebx, ecx                ; Store count of digits
    .L2:                        ; Second loop: load the remainders in reversed order
    pop ax                      ; get back pushed digits
    or al, 00110000b            ; to ASCII
    stosb                       ; Store AL to [EDI] (EDI is a pointer to a buffer)
    loop .L2                    ; until there are no digits left
    mov eax, ebx                ; Restore Count of digits
    ret                         ; RET: EAX length of string
```

Comment: I've downvoted temporarily (hopefully). You do provide a conversion routine, and it is commented, but for someone reading that might not understand what that code is doing in general (and why) may find it confusing. What might be helpful is a general explanation of the algorithm. Nothing fancy, just enough for someone to get a high level understanding of what that code is ultimately trying to accomplish (and a general idea of the mechanism you used).

Comment: Instead of storing `lenUserMsg` in the data section, you could get it into registers with `mov reg, imm`.  (So it would still be an `equ` definition).